# Invalid access to memory location dll

Tags: c++, dll, windows-runtime

Here is the problem:
I'm working on a project with one static library `a.lib`, a standalone executable `a.exe` and a DLL `a.dll`.
Both the DLL and the executable links against the static library `a.lib` and they just wrap code from this library (for info, this is a development tool, the executable is the standalone version of the tool and the DLL is meant to be in loaded from Unity Engine to use this tool in the engine).

The executable works just fine.
However as soon as I declare in the DLL's code: (and nothing else)

```
myLib::A InstanceOfA; // class implementated in a.lib
```

I encounter the error **Invalid access to memory location** when the DLL is loaded. (If the code above is commented the DLL is loaded and executed correctly)

I've checked the UAC as recommanded by other post about this issue without success.

The problem seems clearly to come from the code in the static library which must perform some illegal stuff at some point. However I've not enough information to start debugging.

Note that the dependency walker finds the following dependency missing even when the DLL is correctly loaded and executed (that is when I comment the code above) (so in theory it shouldn't be the source of this issue, right ?)

- `API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL`
- `API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL`
- `API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL`
- `API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL`
- `DCOMP.DLL`
- `IESHIMS.DLL`

I couldn't find a way to link correctly to these DLL. I tried hard!!! :'(

Is there anyway to find more info to get rid of this issues ?

(I'm using VS2015 on Win7)

Comment: The constructor of `myLib::A` is doing something - to help you we need to see it. Or just debug it: put a breakpoint on the line `myLib::A InstanceOfA;` and click step-into.

Comment: Great!! I didn't think that breakpoint would work for the loading!! There is in fact an attempt to access the address NULL in during the loading of the DLL. (Why does it work with the executable is an other story). Thanks for the advice @RichardCritten